# Rails 3 Devise User table is missing authentication_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

My Rails 3 app is using Devise and I noticed that my users table was missing it's authentication_token column. Not sure how it's been authenticating users up until now, but in either case I'm looking to add the authentication_token column to repeat what was done in this tutorial: http://ariejan.net/2011/03/27/rails-3-devise-uploadify-no-flash-session-hacks. How do I go about adding this in?

**Edit**

I did notice that in my `config/initializers/devise.rb` I had this, which I take is an alternative to auth tokens?

```
# If true, uses the password salt as remember token. This should be turned
# to false if you are not using database authenticatable.
  config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true
```

**Edit 2**

I also tried adding the following to my Users model but nothing changed.

```
devise :database_authenticatable
```

Here is my current user model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token authentication is only used for API style authentication where you receive a JSON response from another application. By default Devise uses email and password authentication, which is what the `:database_authenticatable` is configuring.

In order to set your app up this way you can follow either tutorial from the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example). Either one of them will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Can they both be used at the same time? I was under the impression that tokens were created when the user logs in with email and password.

Comment: If you use both then that will enable them to either log in through your web application, or use the token through another application. You will have to setup a token controller to create them through however you choose. Most commonly, in say a mobile, the token is created when the user signs up. They log into the mobile app with username and password, and then it stores the token passed back. From then on, they are logged in with the token.

Comment: I think I was confusing tokens with the sessions Devise uses under the hood when a user logs in using email/password. I don't think tokens are something I want it my application after-all, thanks for clarifying though.